# Localization of a variable value on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, localization

I have around 72 html files in my resource folder and I need to localize them. Now I have translated them in french. A file selection depends on user input so file name is created by a variable. Now the problem is how to localize the value of a variable.

For example, I have following 3 files in resource folder.

1. AAAAA0.html
2. BBBBB28.html
3. CCCCC33.html

I also have these files with in french in resource folder.

1. AAAAA0-French.html
2. BBBBB28-French.html
3. CCCCC33-French.html

Here is my code that is working fine without localization.

---

```
// ViewController.m File

appDelegate2=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] retain];
NSString *getSign2=[appDelegate2.globalString    stringByAppendingString:appDelegate2.globalindex];
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:getSign2 ofType:@"html" ];
```

---

If user input causes the selection of AAAAA0.html then globalString will be "AAAAA",globalIndex will be "0" and getSign2 will Be "AAAAA0".

If user input causes the selection of BBBBB28.html then globalString will be "BBBBB",globalIndex will be "28" and getSign2 will Be "BBBBB28".

If user input causes the selection of CCCCC33.html then globalString will be "CCCCC",globalIndex will be "33" and getSign2 will Be "CCCCC33".

Now I already have a Localizable.string file and my .xib files are already localized(all labels,images and datepicker etc.).

I want to change the value of getSign2 from AAAAA0.html to AAAA0-French.html if user language is french. Similarly it should change to BBBB28-French.html and CCCC33-French.html for BBBB28.html and CCCC33.html respectively.

What should I add in localizable.string to do this? What change should I make in ViewController.m file?

---

I know I can use following

```
NSLocale *locale=[NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *currentlocale =[locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
NSLog(@"Complete Locale: %@",currentlocale);

if (currentocale==@"French") {

    NSString *getSignNew=[getSign2 stringByAppendingString:@"-French"];
    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:getSignNew ofType:@"html" ];
}
```

But this method check conditions in ViewController.m file while I have done all other localization related coding in localizable.string. Will it cause problem when I will submit my application? If this is not the correct solution then please tell me how to fix this problem.

Please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Localized file should be placed in the structure like this:

```
Your.app/
  English.lproj/
    AAAAA0.html     // English localized file
    ....
  French.lproj/
    AAAAA0.html     // French localized file
    ...
  zh_TW.lproj/
    AAAAA0.html     // Chinese localized file
    ...
```

and then [`-pathForResource:ofType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3a) will automatically look up the correct file matching the current locale.

Comment: I copied all french files in french.LPROJ folder but it doesn't detect them automatically. I have 3 .xib files 1. datepickerviewcontroller.xib 2. second.xib 3.third.xib. I have localized all 3 .xib files. It created one french.lproj in main directory that contains datepickerviewcontroller.xib and localizable.string. But it also created french.lproj under classes folder that contains second.xib and third.xib. Why do I have two french.lproj folders. There should be only one. Is it normal to have multiple french.lproj folder. I copied french files in both folders but it is not reading.

Comment: I am reading one array attributes.plist in second.m file suing mainbundle.   NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:NSLocalizedString(@"attributes","") ofType:NSLocalizedString(@"plist",@"") ]; is working fine for attributes-french.plist as "attributes" is not a varible and in my localizable.string file i am using "attributes"="attributes-French"; But same thing doesn't work for getSIgn2 as it is a variable, I tried pathForResource:NSLocalizedString(@"getSign2",@"") and pathForResource:NSLocalizedString(getSign2,@""). How do i fix it?

Comment: @chits: No having a `.lproj` inside another `.lproj` is not normal. If you choose "Localize" in Xcode the `.lproj` file should be created automatically for you.